# Deleted object would be re-saved by cascade when deleting a shared child object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am getting the infamous "deleted object would be re-saved by cascade error" with Hibernate and I need some help to resolve it.

The entity model is as follows: There is a Person, Team and TeamMemberships between them. A Person can belong to many Teams and a Team can have many Persons linking to it, via TeamMembership objects.

Team

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="team", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
private List <TeamMembership> teamMemberships;
```

Person

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="person", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private List <TeamMembership> teamMemberships;
```

TeamMembership

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="teamId", nullable=false)
private Team team;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="personId", nullable=false)
private Person person;
```

So basically the TeamMembership is the "child" of both Person and Team. Everything works correctly when I edit team memberships from the team side. However when I try to edit team memberships from the person side I get this error.
Is the some mapping annotation of mine that is incorrect or that I am missing out? Any other solutions would be much appreciated.

Edit:
I process TeamMemberships on the team side via the TeamController as follows:

First I get the person ids from the jsp. The I call the following method:

```
private List<TeamMembership> processMembershipList (Team team, Long[] personIds, String teamRole) {
    List<TeamMembership> memberships = team.getTeamMemberships();
    boolean isNewTeam = false;

    if (team.getId() == null) {
        isNewTeam = true;
    }

    for (Long personId: personIds) {
        TeamMembership teamMembership = null;
        Person person = personService.getPerson(personId);
        if (!isNewTeam) {
            teamMembership = teamMembershipService.getTeamMembership(team, person, teamRole);
        }
        if (teamMembership == null) {
            teamMembership = new TeamMembership();
            teamMembership.setPerson(person);
            teamMembership.setTeam(team);
            teamMembership.setTeamRole(teamRole);
        }

        memberships.add(teamMembership);
    }
    return memberships;
}
```

And finally:

```
teamService.saveTeam(team);
```

On the Person side I do the same thing via the Person Controller:

Get the team ids and call the following method to process the team memberships:

```
private List<TeamMembership> processTeamMembershipList (Person person, Long[] teamIds, String teamRole) {
    List<TeamMembership> memberships = person.getTeamMemberships();
    boolean isNewPerson = false;

    if (person.getId() == null) {
        isNewPerson = true;
    }

    for (Long teamId: teamIds) {
        TeamMembership teamMembership = null;
        Team team = teamService.getTeam(teamId);
        if (!isNewPerson) {
            teamMembership = teamMembershipService.getTeamMembership(team, person, teamRole);
        }
        if (teamMembership == null) {
            teamMembership = new TeamMembership();
            teamMembership.setPerson(person);
            teamMembership.setTeam(team);
            teamMembership.setTeamRole(teamRole);
        }

        memberships.add(teamMembership);
    }
    return memberships;
}
```

And finally:

```
personService.savePerson(person);
```

Comment: Could you show us the code used to edit team memberships from each side?

Comment: Have you tried toggling the `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` on either side? I don't think it should make any difference, but it's a cheap experiment.

Comment: @TomAnderson: Thanks for the response. I will post the code now.

Comment: @TomAnderson I have edited the original question to include the code I use to edit team memberships.

Comment: Shouldn't `memberships.add(teamMembership);` be inside the `if (teamMembership == null)` block?

Comment: @dcernahoschi: Since we don't see what Neriyan actually does with the memberships list once he's built it, it's hard to say!

Comment: @Neriyan: Unless i'm missing something, you never actually add the `TeamMembership`s to the collections in `Team` or `Person`. Do you do that somewhere you're not showing?

Comment: I also don't see anywhere any entity is being deleted!

Comment: @TomAnderson It seems the `TeamMemberships` objects are added to the collections with `memberships.add(teamMembership);` But they might get in the collection twice if `teamMembership != null`. Might not solve the issue but it doesn't look good to me.